# Emulator display settings in Android-Studio

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

Kindly help me to figure out the issue in flutter emulator and display settings, I've reinstalled android studio, but nothing happened. The device is not working properly too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK3L4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AVD Manager and delete current virtual device and Create new Virtual Device,Choose any Device with Density 560dpi and choose latest android version available and, In Configuration Make sure Your Graphic settings changed to Hardware - GLES 2.0 and Run it...